# linq average count syntax

Tags: linq

I have a table of listings (pk = Id).
The table has a FK to a practicticeprofile by PracticeProfileId
(i.e 1 Practice profile has many listings)

i wouls like to return the AVERAGE number of listings per practice profile

```
int count;
count = (from l in myentity.Listings
        group l by l.PracticeProfileId into g
        select g.Count()).Average();
```

I think i am successfully grouping the listings by practiceprofile, but I am not sure on how to get the total average # of listings

thanks

Comment: I think your code is correct. If not could you provide sample input and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Group By,try following this example :

```
var categories = 
    from p in products 
    group p by p.Category into g 
    select new { Category = g.Key, AveragePrice = g.Average(p => p.UnitPrice) };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to include the count of products in each category, as well as the average unit price.  I haven't be able to find the correct syntax.

```
var categories =
from p in products
group p by p.Category 
into g      
select new { Category = g.Key, 
             ProdsInCat = g.Count(), 
             AveragePrice = g.Average(p => p.UnitPrice) };
```

Edited to add:

This is the correct syntax. I found my error; I defined `ProdsInCat` as `String` instead of `Int`.